# Nested class has unstable name. Fix with @objc with strange param

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9

We have some code where a class is nested in an extension. After opening the project in Xcode 9, we get the 'Nested class has unstable name' warning.
When using Xcode auto-fix, it generate an `@objc` with some (generated?) param.

For example:

```
struct Something {
}

extension Something {

    @objc(_TtCV16MyProject9Something4Some) class Some: NSObject, NSCoding {

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        }

        func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        }

    }
}
```

All this compiles. But what the heck is this `_TtCV16MyProject9Something4Some`?

It seems to be unique because if we use the same one in two places, it will not compile (some generic project level compiler error).

If I replace the `_TtCV16MyProject9Something4Some` with anything else (say `@objc(Something)`), the project compiles fine, but that does not shad any more light really.

One important question, is the param randomly generated or is it an actual link to a real bridging name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But what the heck is this `_TtCV16MyProject9Something4Some`?

It's the (Swift 3) mangled name for `Something.Some`. And as you haven't specified a custom name by which to expose the class to Objective-C, it is also the name by which the Obj-C runtime sees the class (as Obj-C has no concept of nested classes).

Therefore it's also the name that is encoded into an `NSCoding` archive of an instance of that class (allowing the instance to be re-constructed on decoding; the Obj-C runtime will be queried for the class that goes by that name).

The reason why you're getting this error is because [name mangling for nested classes changed between Swift 3 and 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/9206) – and *may well* change again in the future (until Swift is ABI stable at least). Therefore to allow archives encoded with Swift 3 mangled names to be decoded in Swift 4 and above, the compiler is suggesting you expose the class to Obj-C with the Swift 3 mangled name.

If you don't need to provide this backwards compatibility for Swift 3, then you can go ahead and expose the nested class to Obj-C with your own stable name (to ensure *future* mangling changes don't affect archive decoding). In this case, I would recommend something like `@objc(Something_Some)`.

Comment: Shouldn't then `xcrun swift-demangle _TtCV16MyProject9Something4Some` print something like "Something.Some"? It doesn't for me, even if I set the command line tools to Xcode 8.3.3.

Comment: @MartinR Huh, should do – let me download Xcode 8.3.3 and have a look.

Comment: Forget it, `_TtCV9MyProject9Something4Some ---> MyProject.Something.Some`  is correctly demangled. Apparently  OP obfuscated the actual project name :)

Comment: @MartinR Hah, yeah was literally just about to say the length prefix was inconsistent with the module name :)

Comment: Btw, `xcrun swift-demangle -remangle-new _TtCV9MyProject9Something4Some` (from Xcode 9.1) shows the new mangled name "_T09MyProject9SomethingV4SomeCD". Interestingly, both variants demangle to  "MyProject.Something.Some" in Swift 3 and 4.

Comment: @MartinR, hence `'Nested class has unstable name' warning`

Answer (score 2):

I think your class' name might contain a character not supported by Objective-C. In those cases, you can use the `@objc(name)` attribute to provide an alternative name to use in Objective-C, and what you are seeing is an autogenerated unique name. This is also why you can change that with anything you like and it will compile just fine.

There's a section in Apple's docs explaining this, *Configuring Swift Interfaces in Objective-C* in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID55

Comment: While the project name does not contain (I think) unsupported characters, the link, specifically the section under 'Configuring Swift Interfaces in Objective-C', explains what is the arg passed. Thanks!

Comment: I now recall seeing an Apple lecture about this. This is a way to expose Swift code to Objective-C by articulating the function signature.